# How to reinstall Ubuntu with minimal installation

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, ubuntu-minimal, reinstall

Currently I have a computer with a Windows partion and an Ubuntu installation.

Something weird happened with my original Ubuntu instllation.  It came with Kubuntu, and Gnome Shell and Unity.

I want to do a clean installation of 17.04 and install the minimal Ubuntu with only Gnome Shell.

I have the iso from [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A64-bit_PC_.28amd64.2C_x86_64.29_.28Recommended.29).

However, I do not want an additional installation, I want to wipe out *only* my existing Ubuntu installation and replace it with this.

How do I do this?

Also, when I tried, installing from the `us.archive.ubuntu.com` mirror I get "Archive Mirror Errors" and I can't continue the installation.

Is there something I can check on to make this work?

Comment: You just have to know what is in what partitions and you well be fine. If you do not know , check with gparted before you boot the minimal .iso as the minimal iso does not have standard graphical tools.

Comment: See https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-a-minimal-ubuntu-on-old-laptop/